# How to open a program in specific resolution

Tags: display, games, display-resolution

I need to open a full screen game in small size because I want to run my python script the same time the game is running, is there a way to do that?

Comment: [This](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/43106/how-to-set-window-size-and-location-of-an-application-on-screen-via-command-line) is old, but might be worth looking into.

Comment: @KGIII this solution uses xdotool, which does not work on wayland.

Comment: @KGIII that works but the whenever I click on the window it goes back to fullscreen. I guess there is no solution to that?

Comment: Which version of Ubuntu are you using?

Comment: I'm on Ubuntu 20.04

Comment: I took a look around and came up with [this](https://swaywm.org/). It took a ton of keyword choices, but that seems like it might do what you're asking. I've obviously never used it.

Comment: I forgot to mention but I already tried a tiling manager(the pop os one), and didn't work out

Comment: Can you do it with a tty?

Comment: I don't know much about tty, can you help me?